# Wordpress Php auto email to comment author

Tags: wordpress, email, php

I'd love to be able to automatically send a response to the person who comments on a post on my site. Their email is required so I feel as though I should be able to grab that and use php to send an email back to that email address...

I know the basics for a php email go as follows... So I just need help grabbing the authors email and putting it into the mailTo variable

```
<?php

$subject = 'My subject';
$message = "The Message I'd like to send back to the commenter";
$mailTo = get_comment_author_email_link 

mail($mailTo, $subject, $message);
?>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, but not for free, because you haven't tried anything, you just want the code. Welcome to SO, where we help and get help for programming questions.

Comment: Gotchya, sorry about that I've included code that I've been playing with.

Comment: `get_comment_author_email_link` is not a constant (you use it like a constant), but a function, like so: `get_comment_author_email_link()`. Give it a try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you need is to hook to the comment post action with your defined own function as such:

```
 <?php
 function sendMail($id){
     $subject = 'My subject';
     $message = "The Message I'd like to send back to the commenter"; 
     $comment=get_comment($id);
     $mailTo = $comment->comment_author_email ;
     mail($mailTo, $subject, $message);
 }
 add_action('comment_post', 'sendMail');
?>
```

Comment: I feel like it's getting closer... However something still doesn't work. This is what I have going off of your example. Wordpress mentions that I need to first get_comment_author_email however I am putting this in the comments.php file and I am only allowing for 1 comment therefor upon submit of that single comment I'd like to grab the authors email and send them an email

    <?php
    function sendMail(){
        $mailTo = comment_author_email();
        wp_mail($mailTo, 'Subject', 'Message');
    }
    add_action('comment_post', 'sendMail');

Comment: No...I don't think changing the theme file or core file is a good idea. just place the code above in your function.php. it will do the work for you.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this , but dont forget the comment of `webarto` :

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-comment-auto-responder/

Comment: Thanks, I've tried this however it conflicts with some custom code I've already written.

Comment: you must make your plugins with standard ways.if this answer solve your question you must check grean sing to improve your account reputation ;)

Comment: Your answer is more of a comment than an answer actually.

Comment: Thanks bizzare, however this answer does not solve my question. I know how stackoverflow works. What I'm looking to do should not be too complicated and simply pointing out an existing plugin that may or may not work is not much help to me in this case. If you know how I can take the comment authors email and put that into the php mail function that would be what I am looking for. Thank you for trying to help, I appreciate it.